# ESP8266 malloc/calloc-related crashes ("segfaults")

Tags: esp8266

This is sort of the continuation of [this problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/esp8266-constantly-crashes-in-malloc-related-check-poison-neighborsunsigned-sh). After getting hints that the problem I had were related to bad memory, I checked all of my heap-allocating code again and found a malloc that didn't allocate enough memory for an array. After fixing that and fiddling around with calloc, which may be safer for array-related stuff, I think I exposed the actual programming errors themselves. The crash message I get now is:

```
No poison after block at: 0x3fff0fb8, actual data: 0x84 0xf 0xff 0x3f

User exception (panic/abort/assert)
Panic umm_malloc.cpp:422 umm_malloc_core
```

which sounds to me like some sort of ESP segfault. The code where this happens according to the stack trace is the following:

```cpp
Menu* createMenuStructure(ace_time::TimeZone* mainTZ) {
  // create an array of all clock faces, i.e. a pointer to an array of function pointers
  void (**allClockFaces)(T_DISPLAY*, ace_time::ZonedDateTime*);
  // funkiest malloc in the world; undefined behavior? I hope not.
  allClockFaces = (void (**)(T_DISPLAY*, ace_time::ZonedDateTime*)) calloc(DESIGN_MENU_SIZE, sizeof(*allClockFaces));
  // initialize array
  allClockFaces[0] = &basicDigitalCF;
  allClockFaces[1] = &digitalWithSecondsCF;
  allClockFaces[2] = &basicAnalogCF;
  allClockFaces[3] = &binaryCF;
  allClockFaces[4] = &fullDayBinaryCF;
  ClockFaceSelectMenu* cfMenu = (ClockFaceSelectMenu*) malloc(sizeof(ClockFaceSelectMenu));
  cfMenu = new ClockFaceSelectMenu((char**)design_menu, (size_t)DESIGN_MENU_SIZE, allClockFaces);

  // time zone select menu
  TimeZoneSelectMenu* tzMenu = (TimeZoneSelectMenu*) malloc(sizeof(TimeZoneSelectMenu));
  tzMenu = new TimeZoneSelectMenu();

  Menu** allMenus = (Menu**) calloc(3, sizeof(*allMenus));
  // initialize first layer of sub menus
  allMenus[0] = cfMenu;
  allMenus[3] = tzMenu;
  
  OptionsMenu* mainMenu = (OptionsMenu*) malloc(sizeof(OptionsMenu));
  mainMenu = new OptionsMenu((char**)main_menu, (size_t)MAIN_MENU_SIZE, allMenus);
  
  // for now, manually set the sub menu's parent to the main menu. When all menus are finished, the main menu will do this automatically
  allMenus[0]->parent = mainMenu;
  allMenus[3]->parent = mainMenu;
  
  ClockMenu* clk = (ClockMenu*) malloc(sizeof(ClockMenu));
  // timeClient is a global NTPClient variable
  clk = new ClockMenu(&timeClient, mainTZ, (Menu*)mainMenu);
  
  return clk;
}
```

All names containing `Menu` are classes derived from that base class, and the top couple of lines allocate an array of function pointers. And just to be clear: This code was working perfectly fine for the last several days of development until I made some changes to the SD card functionality that caused the constant crashes.

I am not very used to working in manual memory management. Is this way of allocating appropriate, and if so, correct? What am I doing wrong, or does the error lie somewhere else in the (~1500sloc) project?

Edit: Although the issue is already solved, thanks to the approved answer, I wanted to clarify that the constants used in the array allocation are all correct and correspond to the string array's length. E.g. main_menu is a string array of length 5 and MAIN_MENU_SIZE is a constant defined right next to the array definition that is also defined to 5. This is of course necessary as C arrays have no way (that I know of) of finding the length of complex pointer arrays such as these.

Comment: Where are the matching calls to free?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but you should never use `malloc` in C++. It allocates memory without actually creating an object, which results in undefined behavior, which could very well crash your program. You should always be using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_pointer`, `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`) to manage dynamically allocated memory. In the rare case where you do need raw allocations, you can use `new`/`delete`, but never `malloc`/`free`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> ```cpp
> // funkiest malloc in the world
> ```

Funky, indeed. ;-) I kind of like its twisted beauty, but not everyone
does. Some may urge you to `typedef` that function type.

> ```cpp
> allClockFaces[4] = &fullDayBinaryCF;
> ```

Are you sure `DESIGN_MENU_SIZE` is strictly larger than 4? Maybe an
`assert()` would be good to use here.

> ```cpp
> ClockFaceSelectMenu* cfMenu = (ClockFaceSelectMenu*) malloc(...);
> cfMenu = new ClockFaceSelectMenu(...);
> ```

You are assigning a value to `cfMenu` twice in a row, which means the
value assigned first is lost. This is a memory leak. You do not need
`malloc()` here, as `new` takes care of the memory allocation prior to
initializing the object. This error is repeated several times in this
function.

> ```cpp
> allMenus[3] = tzMenu;
> ```

`allMenus` has length 3: valid indices range from 0 to 2. This is an
out-of-bounds array access, and the likely cause of the errors you see.

Comment: OK, the behavior of `new` wasn't exactly clear to me, especially because Arduino isn't exactly standard C++. Thank you for clearing everything up for me and hinting me towards `typedef`.

Comment: Re “_Arduino isn't exactly standard C++_”: It's slightly preprocessed C++. Arduino.h is implicitly included, function prototypes are added for you, and then your code is handed to a regular C++ compiler (namely avr-gcc).

Comment: But which C++ standard? I found that some C++ functionality I researched online would not be accepted by avr-gcc, or needed to be modified. I knew about the implicit function prototypes, which I avoid anyways and just put `void setup(); void loop();` in the beginning of my main files.

Comment: It's C++11 (platform.txt puts “-std=gnu++11” in `compiler.cpp.flags`) with no exceptions, RTTI or STL. The things that are supported (like `new`) generally work as expected.